# Iptables packet src ip not NATed in case of icmp reply and tcp ack

Tags: iptables, netfilter

I am using `iptables` in conjunction with `net-filter` queue in order to alter packets programmatically.

Im using `iptables` rules over ubuntu lab with 2 NICs eth0 to the internet and eth1 to the LAN I have used the well known iptables rules for NATing with masquerading on eth0.

```
sudo iptables --table nat --append POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE 
sudo iptables -append FORWARD -i eth1 -j ACCEPT. 
sudo iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -j NFQUEUE --queue-num 0 
sudo iptables -t mangle -A OUTPUT -j NFQUEUE
```

These 4 rules are used to help me capture packets inside my program and modify packets or drop what I want using `nfq_set_verdict`.

In fact everything is going as I am expecting, that is the three protocol types `icmp`, `tcp` and `udp` packets are modified and reinjected. In the queue then exits eth0 to the internet taking eth0 ip address as source address (effect of using MASQUERADE NAT rule).
That is true for all packets EXCEPT: ICMP ping ***reply*** or TCP ***ACK*** packets.
They exit to the internet taking the private ip of the lan device - 192.168.x.x at eth1 and reaches the other side with this private source ip address.

Any ideas. 
Thx.

Comment: I don't understand how an ICMP ping reply would be generated by an IP behind the masquerade.  How can the internet ping a specific host behind the masquerade; the masquerade is a single IP address, and attempts to ping it should be handled by that IP without any masquerading happening.

Comment: @sourcejedi my friend i am building a tunneling vpn

Comment: @sourcejedi i think that the ubuntu kernel handles the icmp reply and tcp ack packets differently so u can not alter source ip of these packets with the eth0 public ip.

Comment: that's quite an ommission!!  So these packets aren't icmp replies or tcp acks once you've re-injected them; they're encapsulated in some other protocol

Comment: Not other protocol i do not use ESP. I USE the same proto without change just encapsulation.

Comment: I am even more puzzled Are you encapsulating ICMP packet with an extra ICMP header, TCP in TCP, etc?

Comment: Only payloads. This is just it

Comment: Ok that's not encapsulation then.  Encapsulation means you add an extra header, before the header+payload which was handed to you.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_(networking)

Comment: So never mind the encapsulation issue and think it out why would every thing work right but the icmp type reply and tcp ack are not taking eth0 ip as the packet src at exit to the internet just as the rest of the packets.

Comment: I do my encapsulation starting from the network layer so, it is an encapsulation starting from network layer.

Comment: So what you're saying, in answer to my question about how you can possibly solicit an ICMP reply from a host behind this masquerade, is that a computer using this vpn pings the address behind the masquerade, your vpn remaps the address to the masquerade IP, it travels over the internet, reaches the masquerade IP, and that's the machine that maps the address back to the real IP being pinged.

Comment: Any way it has nothing to do with encapsulation if u r following right.

Comment: IF the packet was encapsulated in the normal sense before being handled by masquerading, THEN masquerading should not care whether it was originally an ICMP reply or ICMP echo, because the outermost set of headers would always be your own protocol.  That's why encapsulation (or it's absence) is relevant.

Comment: The case is that  i have 2 networks behind the internet each have the ubuntu vpn behind the adsl connected over eth0 then another pc connected over eth1 (lan ip).

Comment: Anyway: so if you're remapping addresses yourself at both ends in the vpn, the masquerading is for something separate, it's intended for use to access the internet.  If you disabled masquerading it would prevent internet access for the internal pcs, but it would not prevent access over the vpn.  that's the idea, right?

Comment: What u r saying is that what i was expecting. I ping from one lan side to the other pc in the other lan side. The ping request packet from both sides takes the eth0 public ip and the reply packets from both sides arrives with the lan source ip of each.

Comment: Hmm, I still don't understand what the scenario is .  How do you recover the IP of the specific target PC on the LAN, when the ICMP ping request reaches the end of the tunnel?  You've told me you don't wrap the original IP header in your own protocol, so you must have overwritten the original target IP?